# run ansible role with specific playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have one ansible role with this structure:

```
── prepare-workstation.yaml
── group_vars
└── roles
    ├── build-nginx-proxy
    │   ├── defaults
    │   ├── tasks
    │   └── templates
    │   └── nginx.yml
    │
    ├── ca
    │   ├── defaults
    │   ├── handlers
    │   ├── tasks
    │   └── templates
```

and `prepare-workstation.yaml` content is:

```
---
- name: Prepare workstation
  hosts:
    - workstation
  roles:
    - { role: ca}                    
    - { role: build-nginx-proxy }
```

I want `build-nginx-proxy` role run with `nginx.yml` not `tasks/main.yml`.

how can I pass `index.yml` to `build-nginx-proxy` role?

something like this:

```
---
- name: Prepare workstation
  hosts:
    - workstation
  roles:
    - { role: ca}                    
    - { role: build-nginx-proxy, 'nginx.yml' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#if nignx.yml is placed in build-nginx-proxy/tasks/nignx.yml
- name: Run tasks/nignx.yaml instead of 'build-nginx-proxy'
  include_role:
    name: build-nginx-proxy
    tasks_from: nignx.yml
```

or try include_tasks

```
- name: Include tasks from /roles/build-nginx-proxy/tasks/nignx.yml
  include_tasks: /roles/build-nginx-proxy/tasks/nignx.yml
```

here is the [roles documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you want something parametric, use a local var:

```
  roles:
    - role: ca                    
    - role: build-nginx-proxy
      vars:
        mod: ../nginx.yml
```

and in main.yml, you do

```
- include_tasks: "{{ mod }}"
```

its better to put the task nginx.yml in folder tasks,  no need to add `../`